# Some kind of dual boot

Tags: boot, windows

So I have 2 Hard Disks which are running Windows, and one clean Hard Disk with nothing on it.
I'm asking if I can install Ubuntu on that clean Hard Disk, but still being able to select which OS to boot, like when you are using dual boot option.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Newer UEFI or older BIOS? Just be sure to install Ubuntu in same boot mode as your Windows installs either UEFI or BIOS. And if Windows 8 or 10 be sure to turn off Windows fast start up whether UEFI or BIOS. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: If you tell us about the other hardware in the computer, we can give you more detailed advice: Computer brand name and model, RAM size, graphics chip/card (brand name and size), wifi chip/card (brand name and size).

Comment: @sudodus Computer brand name or whatever, is custom build, but if you wonder the motherboard is ASUS M5A78L-M LE, 8GB RAM, nVidia GTX960, don't have an wi-fi.

Comment: @oldfred I only have old BIOS or whatever, based on American Megatrends BIOS, I have Windows 10 and seems working fine, what's the fast start up doing bad though?

Comment: Hibernation and fast startup (semi-hibernation) leave the file system in a state that should not be touched by other operating systems.  Ubuntu does not read it, and cannot create a grub menu item to boot Windows. It does not even recognize that there is Windows, which can cause confusion and make you overwrite Window.  - It seems you have a computer that is powerful enough to run standard Ubuntu and all the flavours of Ubuntu. You should probably boot with the boot option `nomodeset` because of the nvidia graphics, and when booted like that install an nvidia proprietary driver.

Comment: @sudodus So no need to remove the fast staartup. Aand how can i boot in nomodeset?

Comment: I removed fast startup from my dual boot system, but you decide what to do with your computer ;-) See this link and links from it explaining how to use boot options, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808